# How to mention "Add parameter if necessary" for method in javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have a java method which has two parameter current, and as part of agile process the third parameter can also be added as part of development to this method.

I have added javadoc for two parameter:

```
/**
 * This method will simply calculate sum of two no.s
 * 
 * @param a
 *            Number1
 * @param b
 *            Number2
 * @return a+b
 */
public int sum(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Now I want to mention that that developer can add third parameter **(int c)** if needed
[In case of addition of 3 no.s is needed]

I can do it by:

```
/**
 * This method will simply calculate sum of two no.s
 * Add third parameter (int c) if needed
 * 
 * @param a
 *            Number1
 * @param b
 *            Number2
 * @return a+b
 */
```

but I am not sure if it is best practice to do it.

So which is the best suitable way to do it ?

Comment: People actually program like that?

Comment: Use varargs `public int sum(int... is)`.

Comment: Better not to leave "HOW TO"s in the code showing people how to program in Java. Save documentation for "things you can't guess".

Answer (score 0):

That ahould do it.

Javadoc is supposed to document the method (or class, or field) at hand, like you are already doing. It is not capable of (i.e. it does not have specific markups to) specifying allowed modifications to the current method, so what should be done in this case is state, in a plain and clear manner in the method description, the possibility of adding a parameter to it.